# Passing an Index or column value as a **KWARG in groupby aggregate function

Tags: pandas, group-by, aggregate, keyword-argument

I am trying to run an aggregate function on a pandas groupby where I pass one of the columns as a kwarg or arg. I can do this with passing a constant but cannot figure out how to pass a column value.

For example

```
import pandas as pd
import datetime
import numpy as np

def sum_corr(vector, cor):
    a = vector.tolist()
    radicand = sum([a[i]*a[j] * (1 if i == j else cor) for i in range(len(a)) for j in range(len(a))])
    return np.sqrt(radicand)

my_table = pd.DataFrame({'Date':4*pd.bdate_range(datetime.datetime(2017,1,1),periods=4).tolist(),
                      'Name':[i for i in 'abcd' for j in range(4)],
                      'corr':[i for i in [0,1,.5,.8] for j in range(4)],
                      'vals':[1,2,3,4]*4})
```

I can call this with a constant No Problem

```
print(my_table.groupby(['Name','corr'],as_index=False).agg(sum_corr,**{'cor':0}))

  Name  corr      vals
0    a   0.0  5.477226
1    b   1.0  5.477226
2    c   0.5  5.477226
3    d   0.8  5.477226
```

I would like to call this passing in the 'corr' column something like

```
print(my_table.groupby(['Name','corr'],as_index=False).agg(sum_corr,**{'cor':my_table['corr']}))

  Name  corr      vals
0    a   0.0  5.477226
1    b   1.0  10
2    c   0.5  8.062258
3    d   0.8  9.273618
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is not passing a column, the problem is that sum_corr() returns an array when you pass a column, when it should return aggregated (scalar) value if you want to use it in agg() for a groupby object.

For example, if you change the last line in sum_corr() from

```
return np.sqrt(radicand)
```

to

```
return np.sum(np.sqrt(radicand))
```

then your function returns a scalar, and

```
print(my_table.groupby(['Name','corr'],as_index=False).agg(sum_corr,**{'cor':my_table['corr']}))
```

produces no error:

```
Name  corr        vals
0    a   0.0  131.252407
1    b   1.0  131.252407
2    c   0.5  131.252407
3    d   0.8  131.252407
```

This example might not be what you want to achieve, but it illustrates you can pass a column as a kwarg in groupby.agg().